# Decoding Korean text files from the 90s

Tags: emacs, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a collection of .html files created in the mid-90s, which include a significant ammount of Korean text. The HTML lacks character set metadata, so of course all of the Korean text now does not render properly. The following examples will all make use of the same excerpt of text .

#### In text editors such as Coda and Text Wrangler the text displays as

> ╙╦  ╝№бя└К ▓щ╥НВь╕цль▒Ф ▓щ╥НВь╕цль▒Ф

Which in the absence of character set metadata in < head > is rendered by the browser as:

> ÓË ¼ü¡ïÀŠ ²éÒ‚ì¸æ«ì±” ²éÒ‚ì¸æ«ì±”

#### Adding euc-kr metadata to < head >

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=euc-kr">
```

Yields the following, which is illegible nonsense (verified by a native speaker):

> 沓 숩∽핅 꿴�귥멩レ콛 꿴�귥멩レ콛

I have tried this approach with all historic Korean character sets, each yielding similarly unsuccessful results. I also tried parsing and upgrading to UTF-8, via Beautiful Soup, which also failed.

**Viewing the files in Emacs** seems promising, as it reveals the text encoding a lower level. The following is the same sample of text:

> \323\313  \274\374\241\357\300\212
>   \262\351\322\215\202\354\270\346\253\354\261\224 \262\3\
>   51\322\215\202\354\270\346\253\354\261\224

How can I identify this text encoding and promote it to UTF-8?

Comment: Could you post a link to a sample file?

Comment: Here you go: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11471672/sample.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of those octal codes that emacs revealed are less than 254 (or \376 in octal), so it looks like one of those old pre-Unicode fonts that just used it's own mapping in the ASCII range. If this is right, you'll just have to try to figure out what font it was intended for, find it and perhaps do the conversion yourself.

It's a pain. Many years ago I did something similar for some popular pre-Unicode Greek fonts: http://litot.es/unicode-converter/ (the code: https://github.com/seanredmond/Encoding-Converter)

Comment: You can not map Korean characters in 7-bit ASCII range, not even in 8-bit range. There are several thousands of characters in Korean character set. 16-bit coding, such as KS X 1001 or EUC-KR is needed for Korean character set.

Comment: Perhaps a clue, the first character after the '<p>' (0x3c 0x70 0x3e), a carriage return (0x0d) and a space (0x20) is 0xd3 which *is* the "lead byte" for Windows Code Page 949. Output from xxd:  `0000000: 3c 70 3e 0d 20 d3 cb 20 20 bc fc a1 ef c0 8a 20  <p>. ..  ......`

Comment: Unfortunately there seem to be a few characters outside the Windows Code Page 949 specification. It yields results similar to EUC-KR.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it is about finding the correct character encoding and using iconv.

```
iconv --list
```

displays all available encodings. Grepping for "KR" reveals at least my system can do CSEUCKR, CSISO2022KR, EUC-KR, ISO-2022-KR and ISO646-KR. Korean is also BIG5HKSCS, CSKSC5636 and KSC5636 according to Wikipedia. Try them all until something reasonable pops out.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't appear to be that simple. As "╙╦ ╝№бя└К ▓щ╥НВь╕цль▒Ф ▓щ╥НВь╕цль▒Ф" sample shows, these are ascii values outside of the mappings for any Korean encoding standards. As Sean points out, it is likely the machine the text was input from was using a non-standard font, so it will have to be mapped to one of these encodings from the octal values.

Comment: Mostly those are just different names for the same coding system (KSC5636 aka EUC-KR). BIG5 is Chinese not Korean.  Having gone through the sample text with all likely chartacter sets using Emacs, I'd have to guess that the file is already corrupt from failed attempts to "fix" the encoding.  UTF-16-LE produces the most Korean characters, but it also produces a lot of non-characters.  Maybe your best bet if you need to recover the text is to go back to earlier versions of the website using Wayback (archive.org).

Answer (score 0):

Even if this thread is old, it's still an issue, and not having found a way to convert the files in bulk (outside of using a Korean version of Windows7), now I'm using Naver, which has a cloud service like Google docs and if you upload those weirdly encoded files there, it deals with them very well. I just edit and copy the text, and it's back to being standard when I copy it elsewhere.
Not the kind of solution I like, but it might save a few passers-by.
You can register for the cloud account with an ID, even if you do not live in SKorea by the way, there's some minimal english to get by.